# Nuget - Update-Package : Archive file cannot be size 0

Tags: nuget

Has anyone had this error when trying to use the package manager with Nuget? This happens to me when I am using either the GUI or the console.

I have cleared my local cache directory.

```
PM> Update-Package [My Name]
Update-Package : Archive file cannot be size 0.
At line:1 char:15
+ Update-Package <<<<  [My Name]
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], FileFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UpdatePackageCommand

PM>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Unsure what the problem was, I was able to clear the problem by renaming my \package directory and forcing a new one created.

Comment: Just a note that this also happens when opening a Word document using Visual Studio.  The reason? The Word document was created by right-clicking on the Windows (7) desktop and selecting New -> Microsoft Word Document.  This apparently creates an invalid Word document that is not properly formatted.  Word is able to open such a document itself, but the document's presentation on the disk is not in the form of a zip file, as it should be (since the docx extension really hides a zip file underneath).  I would guess that in your case, the package directory was somehow being improperly created.